# JSON Jackon deserialze filepath (String) in json to File object in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using the object mapper from Jackson to map a Json file to a nested set of Java beans. The nested beans and their String, Integer and Enum objects are correctly set in based on what I defined in the Json.

Some of the string represent filepath and it would be nice to have the jackon object mapper directly map the filepath string to a Java file object.

Is this possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it works like that by default. Please, see my example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser parser = jsonFactory.createJsonParser("{\"id\":\"1S200D\", \"path\":\"/tmp/test/file.txt\"}");
        Entity employee = objectMapper.readValue(parser, Entity.class);
        System.out.println(employee);
    }
}

class Entity {

    private String id;
    private File path;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public File getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(File path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity [id=" + id + ", path=" + path + "]";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just declared property as a `File`.